# Load Alamofire result JSON into table view using SwiftJSON

Tags: swift, uitableview, alamofire, swifty-json

I am trying to populate a tableview with JSON data retrieved from a web API.

I have a class for my user model:

```
class UserModel {
    var userID: String?
    var fullName: String?
    var emailAddr: String?

    init(userID: String?, fullName: String?, emailAddr: String?) {
        self.userID = userID
        self.fullName = fullName
        self.emailAddr = emailAddr
    }
}
```

I am trying to populate with:

```
func getUserList(){        
    Alamofire.request("myURL here")
        .responseJSON(completionHandler: { (response) in
            switch response.result {
            case .success(let value):
                ProgressHUD.dismiss()
                let json = JSON(value)
                print(json)

                for (_, _) in json {
                    let user = UserModel(userID: "userID", fullName: "fullName", emailAddr: "email")

                    self.users.append(user)
                }
                self.tableView.reloadData()

                ProgressHUD.dismiss()
            case .failure(let error):
                print(error.localizedDescription)
            }
        })
```

The output of `print(json)` is:

```
[{"userID":"bbloggs","fullName":"Bily Bloggs","email":"bbloggs@bloggs.com"},{"userID":"bnomates","fullName":"Billy Nomates","email":"bnomates@something.org"}]
```

The code does not enter the 'for' block and jumps straight to the `self.tableView.reloadData` line.

Answer (score 0):

Actually you don't need the SwiftyJSON conversion as the result is already an array

```
guard let userArray = value as? [[String:String]] else { return }
for item in userArray {
    let user = UserModel(userID: item["userID"]!, 
                         fullName: item["fullName"]!, 
                         emailAddr: item["email"]!)
    self.users.append(user)
}
```

---

However you are encouraged to drop `SwiftyJSON` and use `Decodable`. It's more efficient and requires less code

```
struct User {
    let userID, fullName, emailAddr: String
}

func getUserList() {        
    Alamofire.request("myURL here")
        .responseData(completionHandler: { (response) in // responseData is crucial
            switch response.result {
            case .success(let data):
                ProgressHUD.dismiss()
                do {
                   self.users = try JSONDecoder().decode([User].self, from: data)
                } catch { print(error) }
                self.tableView.reloadData()

                ProgressHUD.dismiss()
            case .failure(let error):
                print(error.localizedDescription)
            }
        })
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can cast your result as an "array of dictionaries", and then create objects.
Something like this:

```
func getUserList(){
    Alamofire.request("myURL here")
        .responseJSON(completionHandler: { (response) in
            switch response.result {
            case .success(let value):
                ProgressHUD.dismiss()
                let json = JSON(value)
                print(json)

                if let jsonArray = json as? [[String: Any]] {
                    let user = UserModel(userID: "userID", fullName: "fullName", emailAddr: "email")
                    self.users.append(user)
                }
                self.tableView.reloadData()

                ProgressHUD.dismiss()
            case .failure(let error):
                print(error.localizedDescription)
            }
        })
```